How is the operator[] implemented in the std::bitset class
I am trying to reimplement the bitset class for didactic purposes. I stumbled upon the operator[] which seems to be able to both return by value and by reference the bit I am trying to access. I am really confused by this approach since I was thinking to use an array of uchar.
